zipfile.extract для списка
На вход подаётся архив, из которого выделяются файлы с определённым расширением в отдельный список. Нужно через zipfile разархивировать каждый файл из списка.
import zipfile
import os

for root, dirs, files, in os.walk('input'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.zip'):
            os.makedirs(os.path.join(file))
            with zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(root, file)) as zf:
                print('\n'.join(zf.namelist()))
                for file in zf.namelist():
                    if file[-4:] == ".mp3" or file[-4:] == ".ogg":
                        neededFiles = []
                        neededFiles.append(file)
                        print(neededFiles)
                        zf.extract(neededFiles, os.path.join(file)) # это


Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

zf.extract принимает ровно один файл для распаковки за раз. и он у вас есть на каждой итерации, то есть file. Просто его и передайте, а не список.  (ну и попутно разберитесь со вторым параметром, а то вы совсем справку не читаете)
